# Spring Security forces log in screen even with permit all specification

Tags: java, spring

I have a basic spring security filter chain with form login. And whenever I try to bypass the login screen it just redirects back to it.

Specifically, trying to access public still redirects back to the login page.

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain (HttpSecurity sec) throws Exception
    {
        sec.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("home/normal")
                .hasRole("NORMAL")
                .requestMatchers("home/admin")
                .hasRole("ADMIN")
                .requestMatchers("/home/public", "/home/add")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin();
        return sec.build();
    }
```

Comment: What are these paths > `/home/public`,  `home/add`, HTML pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this could happen not because of the `/home/public` nor `/home/add` when you request a page from the server, browsers will request the favicon as well so they issue `/favicon.ico` request against the server so make sure to allow it as well

So update your code as follows:

```
...
.requestMatchers("/home/public", "/home/add", "/favicon.ico")
.permitAll()
```

You can open the dev tools in the browser and check the network tab if there are any XHR requests against a server that needed to be allowed also.